# How can I tell if the checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to be able to tell if the checkboxes are checked to do some basic validation. Problem: I don't have access to the PHP generating this. There is no class added, or the basic checked=checked that most forms have. What's the easiest way to target the checked boxes?

http://www.inpresence.in/event-registration?ee=4

EDIT: freak out!! here's the code, i just need to target the checked boxes, everything else is working. the :checked method of jquery uses checked=checked within the checkbox, which isn't there.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    //when the submit button is clicked...
    $("input.btn_event_form_submit").click(function(){

    //find the value of the drop down with one evening or four evenings
    var priceOption = $("#price_option-4").val();

    //match a string ending with "one evening" as the first numbers will be randomly generated by php
    var oneEvening = /^\d{2}\|One Evening$/.test(priceOption);

    //match a string ending with "four evenings" as the first numbers will be randomly generated by php
    var fourEvenings = /^\d{2}\|Four Evenings$/.test(priceOption);

    //HOW DO I GET THE CHECKED BOXES?!
    var checkedBoxCount = $('#dates-1351733097 .valid').is(':checked').length;

    //if one evening is selected make sure the checked boxes count does in fact equal one
    if(oneEvening && checkedBoxCount != 1){
        //if it doesn't alert the user and return false
        alert('You must select one date');
        return false;
    }

    //if one evening isn't selected, four is. make sure the count does indeed in 4
    else if (fourEvenings && checkedBoxCount != 4){
        //if it doesnt alert the user and return to the form
        alert('You must select four dates');
        return false;
    }

    //else, everything checks out!
    else {
        return;
    }

});
});
```

Comment: are you trying to validate in PHP or in JavaScript or magically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this JavaScript code you can check if a checkbox is checked:

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById("my-checkbox").checked;
```

Or using jQuery:

```
var isChecked = $('#my-checkbox').is(':checked');
```

EDIT: Try this and tell me if it works:

```
var checkedBoxCount = $('#dates-1351733097 .valid:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using jquery to resolve this? 
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

```
$('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked');
```

Comment: he didn't specify that he wanted jquery

Comment: @Landon: He didn't specify that he doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - actually he sort of did, by not tagging the question with the jQuery tag.

Comment: sorry for the confusion: yeah jquery

Comment: @adeneo: I don't think it really works that way. jQuery is just a Javascript library, so its use is a perfectly valid solution to a general Javascript problem. You can't expect the OP to tag the question with the solution: "Hi is there a way to play music from my C++ program?" "Sure - use BASS." "No, that's wrong, he didn't tag the question `bass-library`." ":("

Comment: Putting jquery on a page just for this one case is completely ridiculous.  I *love* jquery, but if you just need it for one thing, as simple as this, you should use native javascript as i posted below

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - what the frack are you talking about. The tags are there so the question ends up in the right category and gets the appropriate answers. Would it be ok to answer a C++ question with PHP code just because there was no "NO-PHP PLEASE" tag on the question. And I agree with Landon, using jQuery for something that is actually easier to do in plain JS is nonsense unless you're already using jQuery. I see the tag is now added to the question, so I guess jQuery answers are OK, but tagging the question correctly is key to get the proper answer.

Comment: @adeneo: C++ and PHP are completely unrelated so your analogy is pretty random. jQuery is a Javascript library. You cannot tag the question with the answer - when you post a question it is because you do not know the answer. In this case, "use jQuery" is part of the answer. Are you now expecting every OP to tag the question with every technology that could be the answer? Even those he doesn't know about? No. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery `:checked` selector. http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a boolean in javascript of what you want:

```
document.getElementById("Nov.12-4_1").checked
```

You can view source and find the elements to view whatever id's they have.

Other answers: the OP didn't specify that he wanted a jquery answer.  If he hasn't used jquery for anything up to this point. I think adding it just for this would be a tad overkill.